# SQL JOIN query for Cakephp

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

I have 2 tables, one is called **items**, and the other is called **sliders**.

I want to call all the columns where **sliders.item_id = items.id** , 
and both are published so **items.published=1** and **sliders.published=1**. But also I want to call  **sliders.item_id**'s that are NULL.

So basicly is like a right join where i get all related record that match the constrain but also records on the sliders table that don't correspond to items table.

In few words the point is this: i want to get ALL sliders that belongs to items (sliders.item_id=items.id) AND (sliders.published=1 AND items.published=1) BUT also sliders where item_id=null.

I have made a working query, but it does not satisfy me.

```
select *
from items
right join sliders
on items.id = 27
and items.id = sliders.item_id
and items.published = 1
where sliders.published = 1
```

**THE TABLES**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `item_description` text NOT NULL,
  `published` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sliders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pic_path` text NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

First i want it in basic MySQL query because i can convert in cakephp later.

Comment: Just to note - RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare, I assume because LEFT JOINs are more intuitive.

Comment: Can you give data with expected output?

Answer (score 1):

try this query,

```
SELECT *
FROM items 
RIGHT JOIN sliders
ON items.id = sliders.item_id
WHERE items.published = 1 AND sliders.published = 1
```

Comment: Thank you ravikumar, but this is what i have done, i was thinking if was a better way, anyway thnx.

Answer (score 1):

**when u got all record from table which are published from both :**

$SQL = "SELECT * 
FROM items
RIGHT JOIN sliders
ON items.id=sliders.id
WHERE items.published=1 AND sliders.published=1";

**And when u want to get particular id record..**
$id=27

$QRY = "SELECT * 
FROM items
RIGHT JOIN sliders
ON items.id=sliders.id
WHERE items.published=1 AND sliders.published=1 AND items.id= $id";

**and if you want to get more then one id records then...**
$ids="27,28,29,30,50,55";

$QRY = "SELECT * 
FROM items
RIGHT JOIN sliders
ON items.id=sliders.id
WHERE items.published=1 AND sliders.published=1 AND items.id in($ids)";

in last query u fetch records which is published in both table and id from the above.